# How to get the cell address of max (duplicates)? randomly returning any max duplicate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

10, 10, 5, 1

Starting at cell A1

`=max(A1:A4)` =10 (there are 2 in this case)

I'm using the following to find the cell address for MAX.

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A1:D1,MATCH(MAX(A1:D1),A1:D1,0)))
```

I want to be able to find the cell address for the duplicate (10 in B1) as well.

Furthermore,

When the max value has duplicate, I want it to randomly return the cell address of the max value.

For example:

10, 10, 5 , 1  = answers can be: A1 or B1

15, 3, 15, 15 = answers can be: A1 or C1 or D1

the function probably need a combination of these?

```
=if(countif(A1:D1, max(A1:D1)>1,randbetween(0, countif(...) ),  )
=cell("address",  )
=index(match) ?
```

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139574) is a solution for your query

Comment: For the set 15, 31, 15, 15, surely 31 is the maximum?

Comment: @XORLX thanks, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Array formula****:

`=CELL("address",INDEX(1:1,INDEX(MODE.MULT(IF(F1:I1=LARGE(F1:I1,{1;1}),COLUMN(F1:I1))),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(F1:I1,MAX(F1:I1))))))`

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work properly when I don't start from A1. For example, Starts from F5

Comment: I don't understand your first comment. As to your second, if the range is not actually A1:D1, then obviously you need to amend this everywhere in the formula. What's more, if the range is not a horizontal one (e.g. A1:D1) but a vertical one (e.g. A1:A4) then my formula will require a small amendment.

Comment: your function is great, and I did change the range accordingly. It is horizontal and I did ctrl,shift,enter it. The bottom line works, and top doesn't. http://i.stack.imgur.com/SVevf.jpg

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "The bottom line works, and top doesn't". Can you be more specific?

Comment: Have just seen your picture. The array constant in the formula you are using, i.e. {1,1} is not the same as that I gave {1;1}. Why did you change it?

Comment: Thanks for the checking and reply. It is a ; same as the original. The top part of ; is small and close to the "1" making it uneasy to recognize.

Comment: Sincere apologies. Have amended.

Comment: It works now, awesome. I will search on the function you used. Many thanks!

Comment: @XORLX how does your answer differ from mine? yours is returning the second instance of the max duplicate value and mine returns the first one, right? as far as I can understand from the question, the formula can return any instance of it, so why go for an array formula in this case?

Comment: @AHC No. Mine returns a RANDOM choice from those which share the maximum, as the OP requested.

Comment: @AHC, I appreciate your help too. For this specific question, XORLX answered what I am after. The "returned value (cell address)" will change if you refresh the worksheet or if you type in some other cells.

Answer (score 0):

here is the formula, but it returns the first max address:

```
=CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,0,MATCH(MAX(A1:D1),A1:D1,0)-1))
```